# Is the number of characters really all this site is about?

Tags: discussion

So, code golf is about writing solutions in the smallest amount characters.

But, my question is more around the overall goal of the site. Is it really just about number of characters or about improving problem solving by solving puzzles,etc?

Thoughts?

Comment: Trying to help with this. See http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/302/new-contest-type-proposal and an example question http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2357/78.

Answer (score 18):

I'm hoping more for interesting problems to solve in order to improve my general coding abilities.  I don't really see the skills practiced by golfing as practical and am not really interested in it, so I for one hope for other problems.

Comment: Nothing to add. Just vote like 5 others )

Comment: Go ahead submit some interesting and novel problems! :-)

Answer (score 3):

I would also like to see more interesting problems of which the point isn't just to golf the lowest, but also (or instead, in some cases) to provide a problem-solving challenge or whatever. And I think golfing has its place as a competition. But I imagine that, if you participate in golfing, in an effort to lower your score, you will probably explore the language you're in more, teach yourself optimization, and possibly branch out to learn new languages.

But that's just an educated guess. I haven't really done any real golfing yet.

Answer (score 3):

When I committed to codegolf.SE, I was under the impression that the site is about programming puzzles in general not just code golf. I hope that still holds true.

I enjoy code code golf as much as the next guy, but being only about code golf IMHO is a little too narrow for my tastes. It is possible that I am in the minority here (in which case ignore my post), but I for one really would like this site to be about programming puzzles in general.

Comment: You're definitely not alone. See http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5/site-title-and-domain where me and a couple others want to de-emphasize code golf.

Answer (score 0):

> Beta Q&A site for code golfers and for
>   those who interested in code golfing
>   (from beginners to experts), and
>   programming puzzles.

Comment: So am I the only one who finds that definition limiting?

Comment: Your question asked if the site was limited to code golf "or about improving problem solving by solving puzzles."  I'm confused about how you're still confused.

Comment: @Sugerman The thing is 53/83 questions are tagged `[code-golf]`. Obviously the "and programming puzzles" is not strong enough. People are even answering non-golf questions as if they were code golfs. This needs to be fixed if we want to consider ourselves a general puzzle site.

Comment: Read through those 53 [code-golf] questions and look at how many answers don't even make attempt at golfing.  There needs to be a distinct clear signal when a question is golf or something else.

Comment: @Sugarman Many were tagged `[code-golf]` a while after the question was posted. It's already been discussed that the tag is the [best way to specify a question as code golf](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/59/golf-versus-non-golf-questions), but if we actually *got* more non-golf questions such that code golf dropped under say 25% then we will probably need to specify this more clearly. Right now, we're waiting to see if that happens before discussing how to solve a problem we might never have.

Comment: Honestly, if the issue is that the site is dominated by code-golf and needs more diversity, I'd suggest changing the name.  Naming this site code-golf is like naming a Q&A site about cars "chevyimpala.stackexchange.com"